# LiteMage Cache not working for logged in users in Mangento2

Tags: magento2, caching, litespeed, litemage

For my magento 2 website which uses Litemage cache, Once the litemage cwral is done I can see public pages are being cached. I wanted to cache private pages as well. For private cache, Actually, I checked using multiple user accounts. When one user logs in and visits a particular page, it is cached for all the logged-in users. Is there a way way for the private cache to be prebuilt for logged in users?

I logged in with a different user account and checked the same page, and it is getting cached. So, it seems like we need to visit all the pages with one user account in order for the cache to work for all the logged-in users. Is that correct?

If so, could you please let me know whether there is any solution to crawl the website as a logged-in user?

Answer (score 0):

- Litemage Cache primarily focuses on caching public pages in Magento 2 websites.
- By default, private or user-specific pages are not cached to maintain personalized content delivery for logged-in users.
- Caching private pages can be challenging due to dynamic and personalized content.
- It is recommended to separate public and private sections, with public pages being cached and private pages dynamically generated.
- Implementing user-specific caching would require a custom solution considering the specific requirements of your website.

Comment: Can you please share some reference docs for the same?  if this is possible?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html